# Как расставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Как здесь расставить запятые? Это уточняющие обстоятельства, и тогда выделение требуется с двух сторон, или просто однородные члены?

18 декабря 2014 г. в Санкт-Петербурге, в Особняке Нейдгарта состоялся торжественный вечер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уточнение – не "в Санкт-Петербурге", а "в особняке", естественно. Требует обособления.

Однородными членами быть ну никак не могут.

И "особняк" пишется со строчной.